# C#: params keyword vs. list

Tags: c#, optimization, list, parameters

What are the pro/cons of using the params keyword vs. a List as input to some c# function?

Mainly what are the **performance** considerations and other trade offs.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The params keyword is syntactic sugar handled by the C# compiler. underneath the hood, it's actually turning

```
void Foo(params object[] a) { ... }
Foo(1,2,"THREE");
```

into

```
void Foo(object[] a) { ... }
Foo(new object[] { 1, 2, "THREE" })
```

From a *performance* perspective like you're asking about, the params call is simply faster because it is a bit faster to create an array than it is to create a List<>. There is no performance difference between the two snippets above.

Comment: If we would pass an existing List reference, then it would be slower to use params because of the overhead of allocating memory for array.

Comment: @Mert: But you also had to allocate memory for the list<> you are passing as a reference...

Comment: @Mert Whether or not it already exists makes no difference unless `Foo()` is called multiple times using the same List.

Comment: @Dan, Nope, if the list already exist you just pass it as reference to the method that takes a list as parameter. If you pass a list to method with params as parameter, you need to allocate space and copy that list into an array and use that array as argument. So it makes a difference.

Comment: @Mert, `params object[]` takes `object[]` as input without copying it, so your existing `List<object>` still has more overhead than passing an existing `object[]`.

Answer (score 27):

Personally I use `params` when writing functions that take a number of inputs provided by *another programmer* (for example `String.Format`), and `IEnumerable` when writing functions that take a list of data items provided by *the computer* (for example `File.Write`).

The performance implications are negligible. Worrying about the performance of a trivial thing like this is *exactly* what Donald Knuth was talking about in the famous "premature optimization is the root of all evil" quote.

That said, the asker seems to be fixated on it, so here you go:

Results for 10 million iterations:

```
params took 308 ms
list took 879 ms
```

From these results we can see that the params array is just over twice as fast. The simple fact that you can call either of these things **Ten Million Times** in under a second means that you're completely wasting your time by worrying about it. Use whatever suits your code the best.

The code to test it (compiled and run in release mode using VS2008)

```
class Program
{
    const int COUNT = 10000000;

    static IEnumerable<string> m_value = null;

    static void ParamsMethod(params string[] args)
    { m_value = args; } // do something with it to stop the compiler just optimizing this method away

    static void ListMethod(List<string> args)
    { m_value = args; } // do SOMETHING with it to stop the compiler just optimizing this method away

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
            ParamsMethod("a", "b", "c");

        Console.WriteLine("params took {0} ms", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        s.Reset();
        s.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; ++i)
            ListMethod(new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" });

        Console.WriteLine("list took {0} ms", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because List creation time is slow. if you call A method that takes IEnumerable with say, a string[] instead of a List<string> the performance would be nearly equivalent to the params method.

Comment: Sure it would, but it doesn't matter!

Comment: You may be onto something but could you elaborate this point please: *data items provided by the computer (for example File.Write)*. There is no `File.Write` and I am having a hard time to distinguish between inputs by a programmer vs. computer. When writing APIs, SDKs, how would you know if it would be a programmer or computer?

Comment: @CodingYoshi what I was attempting to refer to was for example feeding the output of one function into another (provided by the computer) vs the developer typing the list in themselves (provided by the programmer)

Answer (score 2):

The params keyword allows you to dynamically pass a variable number of arguments to the function without worrying about compiler errors like this:

```
public string PrefixFormatString(string p, string s, params object[] par)
{ 
    return p + string.Format(s, par);
}
...
PrefixFormatString("COM", "Output Error #{0} - Error = {1}", errNum, errStr);
```

If you pass a list, you have to construct the list before you can pass it in:

```
public string PrefixFormatString(string p, string s, List<object> par)
{ 
    return p + string.Format(s, par.ToArray());
}
...
List<object> l = new List<object>(new object[] { errNum, errStr });
PrefixFormatString("COM", "Output Error #{0} - Error = {1}", l);
```

and it tends to hide the meaning of what type of data the function is expecting.

Note that this is very similar to passing a simple array variable.  The only difference is that the compiler will fix up the parameters into an array for you...   I'm not 100% sure, but I think the technical difference is just syntactical sugar - in either case you are really passing an array of whatever type the parameter is.

Comment: This isn't the type of issue that you really should be worrying about performance - I'm sure there are much larger performance hogging problems in whatever you are considering.  The performance is virtually the same, because of the fact (I think) that it's mainly just a compiler syntax, and has nothing to do with the way the function itself gets called once it's in IL.

Answer (score 2):

Well, with the params keyword you could enter arguments into a method like this:

```
MethodName(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

But with a list, you'd do it like this:

```
MethodName(new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4});
```

The syntax can be a bit more clear in the former than the latter. This is useful when you just have one parameter to pass in:

```
// params
MethodName(1);

// List
MethodName(new List<int> {1});
```

Comment: See... honestly I think THIS is the right answer to the question being asked.

@YaronNaveh - the performance is close enough as to be negligible. Performance isn't a question in this case, it's design - reuse, maintenance, support...

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `params` allows for a nicer syntax when calling it, but the list (assuming you mean `IList<>`) is more flexible because different classes may implement the interface. Passing a `List<>` only makes sense if you need to perform specific operations on the list which are not supported by the interface (such as `ToArray()`).

Comment: +1 for IList<T>, or any other relevant interface depending on what your collection needs to do.

Comment: If you only need to enumerate the items, then IEnumerable<T> is a better choice than IList<T>, allowing you to pass in a bunch of different collection implementations as well as LINQ query results, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`params` is a language construct for functions taking a variable number of parameters. It is similar to C elipses specifier - i.e. `printf(char* fmt, ...)`. The language supports this kind of operation, might as well use it, especially if it makes the code easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between the two that I can see is that the number of parameters passed into the method is set at compile time using `params`, while with a `List<T>` it depends on the list passed in at runtime.

Whether fixing the number of arguments that your method must be called with at compile time is a pro or a con depends entirely upon your design and intent for it.  Either can be a benefit depending on what you are hoping to achieve.

`Params` helps on the readability front, and is as close to an optional parameter that you're going to get to in C#.  I would only use the `List<T>` implementation personally if I needed to consume an unknown number of parameters at any point.

Edit: just spotted your edit regarding performance issues.  On that topic I'm unsure, although if you could potentially expect a large number of 'parameters' using `List<T>`, whereas `params` has a sanity cap on it due to them having to be coded.

Answer (score 0):

The performance of the **programmer** calling your method can sometimes be improved by your usages of the params keyword.

(Given that programmers cost so much more then computers, why are you thinking of any other sort of performance.)

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I would skip the params.  I've been bitten by it once or twice.  How?  Let me explain.

You write a public method with this signature:

```
public static void LogInUser(string username, string password, params string[] options)
```

You test it, it works, its done... and another assembly/application is calling your function.

Now, a month later you want to change your signature to add user role:

```
public static void LogInUser(string username, string password, string role, params string[] options)
```

Oh how things have changed for anything calling your method.

```
LogInUser("z@z.com", "zz", "Admin", "rememberMe", "800x600");
```

Comment: Also, the params "smells" like it used frequently for Interop.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't have that problem if you grouped your defined members in a single object, like `Credentials`.

Comment: Dynami, you are absolutely correct.  Bad code... bad use of params.